# How to convert AVCaptureStillImageOutput to UIImage and save as NSData?

Tags: ios, uiimage, swift2, nsdata, avcapture

I am trying to send a photo with the app I am working on, I have made the app to take a photo and then when you tap on send it would send the photo you just took to send it through mail.

But I don't know how to convert the photo that is of type `AVCaptureStillImageOutput` to `UIImage` and store it in a `NSData` in order to use it as an attachment in `addAttachmentData`.

I tried to do this:

```
let data: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image: stillImageOutput)
```

I have this function

```
func doSomethingWithImage(image: UIImage) {
        // do something here
        mc.addAttachmentData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: imageAsUIIMage)!, CGFloat(1.0))!, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "backupOne.jpeg")
    }
```

But It shows me an error, "Use of unresolved identifier 'imageAsUIIMage'

I want to get the UIImage in order to send it through an e-mail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get capture an image and save it to file and convert it to `UIImage` using `stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection()`

```
// setup code
stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

captureSession.startRunning()

let connection = stillImageOutput.connectionWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection(connection) { (sampleBuffer, error) in
    // NSData of jpeg data. Save to file and add as email attachment.
    let jpegData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.doSomethingWithJPEGImageData(jpegData!)
    })
}

// later on
func doSomethingWithJPEGImageData(jpegData: NSData) {
    mc.addAttachmentData(jpegData, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "backupOne.jpeg")
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Where should I put that?

Comment: After you create your `AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto` capture session and add the `stillImageOutput` to it.

Comment: Did that fix the problem?

Comment: Sorry! Is because the camera I had in my app stopped working so I have to fix it  in order to test this code!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the help, but how can I use it in the "addAttachmentData" when I try to use it it says: "Use of unresolved identifier 'imageAsUIImage"

Comment: Is this a new question? If so, start a new question. Is your old question answered?

Comment: NO, this isn't  a new question, I don't know how to take out the imageAsUIImage of the scope to use it.

Comment: ah, I added a method in which you can do something with the image

Comment: Sorry but I am kind of a noob and I don't know what to do next with that function, I have this:

func doSomethingWithImage(image: UIImage) {
            // do something here
            mc.addAttachmentData(UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage(named: imageAsUIIMage)!, CGFloat(1.0))!, mimeType: "image/jpeg", fileName: "backupOne.jpeg")
        }
But it shows me an error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93938/discussion-between-pixele9-and-rhythmic-fistman).